# What Framework should I use to edit VB6 Projects?

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I have a VB6 project that I need to edit. I have downloaded the Visual Studio 2010, but I have read that I need VB6. I have googled but I can't find where I can download VB6.

It is possible to edit this VB6 project with Visual Studio 2010? If not, what can I do?

Best Regards,

Comment: Just to clarify, an IDE is not a "framework."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just download the older versions of Visual Studio that are used to edit VB6 projects, AFAIK there has never been an Express edition put out for the older version.

Your best bet may be to:

- pick up a second hand copy from online, i.e. eBay
- use VS2008 or VS2010 and upgrade the VB6 project to .Net
- enrol in the BizSpark program if you are eligible

Comment: The BizSpark program is still providing VB 6?

Comment: @Cody - my understanding is that you get a MSDN subscription and its available through that. I don't have a BizSpark sub though, so i can't say for sure.

Comment: VB6 Enterprise (and VB1,2,3 and 4 for that matter) comes with MSDN-Pro.